# method_missing-like functionality in objective-c (i.e. dynamic delegation at run time)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, reflection, dynamic, delegation

I'm trying to transform one method call into another dynamically (at runtime).

For instance, I'd like the following:

```
[obj foo]
```

to delegate to:

```
[obj getAttribute: @"foo"]
```

(I'd like to do this dynamically as I don't know ahead of time what those method names or attributes are going to be).

I see that there's a hook into:

```
 - (id) forwardingTargetForSelector: (SEL) aSelector
```

That only seems to work for delegation, though, I want to keep the object as "self" and transform the method arguments.

Where should I look for this sort of behavior?  Is it even possible in obj-c?

Comment: This is a working example of how to implement it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19661059/171933

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the method `-forwardInvocation:` for that. It takes a full `NSInvocation` object which represents the method call, and you can handle it however you wish. If you do this, you should also override `-methodSignatureForSelector:` to return the correct `NSMethodSignature` (required for `-forwardInvocation:` to work on unknown selectors). It's also recommended that you override `-respondsToSelector:` to declare that you can handle the selector in question.